# addthis & google analytics did not pass HTML validation

Tags: html, validation, google-analytics, addthis

These are the errors and warnings I got:

> Line 135, Column 134: & did not start a character reference. (&
> probably should have been escaped as `&amp;.)Rk44QGJO&hl=he"></script><noscript><iframe src="…`
>
> Line 135, Column 309: The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
> …ight="300" width="500" frameborder="0">
> <textarea name="recaptch…
>
> Line 161, Column 116: Attribute addthis:url is not serializable as XML 1.0.

> Attribute addthis:title is not serializable as XML 1.0.

> Attribute addthis:description is not serializable as XML 1.0.

> Attribute addthis:url not allowed on element div at this point.

> Attribute addthis:title not allowed on element div at this point.

> Attribute fb:like:layout is not serializable as XML 1.0.
>
> Attribute fb:like:layout not allowed on element a at this point.

and this is the addthis code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style"
     addthis:url="http://www.example.com"
     addthis:title="title"
     addthis:description="description">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet" lang="en"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_linkedin_counter"></a>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix these errors?

Comment: What are you using to do your validation and is there a reason you need to validate this way? It looks like you're trying to validate against XML syntax, which says that attributes can't contain a ':' http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes.

Also, I don't see anything about Google Analytics in your question - was there a problem with analytics too?

Answer (score 4):

To fix attribute `fb:like:layout`, you can actually remove the following: `fb:like:layout="button_count"`

since the button count is the default layout.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but maybe it helps someone else? I haven't actually tried this implementation myself, but reviewing the code it looks like a good "hack" fix to your problem - providing that you're already using jQuery on your site.

I know people will say "don't worry about it, it's not breaking anything", but when you religiously validate your code (which I believe you should, to find missing closing tags that you've forgotten, etc), these kinds of pesky errors just get in the way of validating your code in the quickest possible way.

Anyway, here is the link: http://www.teslina.com/1879/allgemein/addthis-html5-workaround-js-hack/#sthash.4dHK9Zwl.mkBH3Z0g.dpbs